# My Search Bar Is Not Working

Tags: uisearchbar, searchbar

I want to make a search bar. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }
    else {
        self.allUsers = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];

self.searchedUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.allUsers count]];
self.searchUsers = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
self.doSearch = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchUsers        contentsController:self];
self.doSearch.delegate = self;
self.doSearch.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.doSearch.searchResultsDelegate = self;



}

- (void) fileterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText {
[self.searchedUsers removeAllObjects];
for (NSDictionary *item in self.allUsers)
{
    NSComparisonResult result = [[item objectForKey:@"name"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0,       [searchText length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        [searchedUsers addObject:item];
    }
}
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
return YES;
}
```

Can someone please fix this code? I have followed tons of tutorials and none of them have worked. I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You are asking here what the problem is? How about stating what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It gives me the error: no visible @interface ViewController declares the selector filterContentForSearchText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on the method name: `fileterContentForSearchText:`

Should be: `filterContentForSearchText:`

Comment: Thank you! I should really check my spelling :)